# SpringBootTest javax.validation.ValidationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am testing my annotated javax validations. They work fine in the application with `@Valid` annotation on the method argument. but when I try to test them by manually build the validation factory using

```
Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
```

I get the following error.

> javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead

After getting this error I added `compile "org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.0"` in my gradle file and it started working. Why, the validations are working in the application without requiring the `org.glassfish:javax.el` but requires when manually building the Validation factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate Validator requires an implementation of the Unified Expression Language for evaluating dynamic expressions in constraint violation messages.

When the application runs in a Java EE container, an EL implementation is already provided by the container that's why no need to add an additional dependency.